# My subdomain ssl certificate is clashing with ssl certificate of my main domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS ec2 to deploy my server code and using S3 for static web hosting for my react project. I have routed my subdomain at AWS ec2 and generated its SSL certificate using certbot. And my main domain is pointed to the s3 bucket and generated its SSL certificate using AWS CloudFront. So, whenever I hit my main domain using any web browser, it shows the below error:

```
This server could not prove that it is domain.com, its security certificate is from subdomain.domain.com
```

So, can anyone help me in this situation? I am stuck here for 1 day.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which domains did you use registered for the ssl certificate?

Comment: I am using pickcode.co.in domain.